# Get item that caused context menu to open?

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there a way to get the element the user right clicked on to open a [context menu](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index)?

( The only method i see is looking for an item with `.k-state-focused`.. hopefully, there is a better way )

edit: in [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/crobgjyf/1/) context menus are created using a filter and not a target.

Comment: I think you should use the in-built `open` event as given in the documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/contextmenu#events-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in `target` field of the event object received by you Event Handler.

Example:

```
$("#container").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
    console.log("target", e.target);
});
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/crobgjyf/

Comment: Hello @OnaBai, in my code i create the menus using a filter (see edit link in original post). when i use `target` i get the entire html body.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/crobgjyf/2/. Is this what you want? What are you expecting?

Comment: apologies on delay on accepting the answer, had no access to the code. thank you.